# How to properly stop a Spring Boot app in Android Studio?

Tags: spring-boot, android-studio

When I try to stop a Spring Boot app in Android Studio by clicking the stop button on the top right corner of Android Studio the stop button remains enabled although the app is already terminated.

[image]

I don't have this problem when I stop an Android app in Android Studio.

[image]

I know that Android Studio is build for the Android development, not for the Spring Boot development, but since our frontend is an Android app and backend is a Spring Boot app, it's more convenient to develop both apps in one IDE, instead of switching between Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

Since Android Studio is just a modified version of IntelliJ IDEA, running a Spring Boot app in Android Studio is exactly the same as it is in IntelliJ IDEA, but stopping it apparently requires some extra effort.

When I stop a Spring Boot app with the stop button it prints the following message to the console, could that be a reason ?

```
Process finished with exit code -1
```

**Reproduce this issue:**

1. Create a new Android project (Empty Activity)
2. Create a new Spring Boot Web project on https://start.spring.io
3. Add Spring boot Web project as a module to the Android project
4. Run the Spring Boot module
5. Stop the Spring Boot module with the stop button on the top right corner of Android Studio

**Expected/actual:**

I expect the stop button to become disabled after the Spring Boot app is terminated, but it remains enabled.

Comment: This should be on Jetbrains support